# compare two tables on SQL server with result to show which column from its associated table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, windows-7

I need to compare two tables on SQL server.

```
table1 
id  value
3     5 

table2
id  value
8     6 

SELECT *
FROM
( 
    SELECT a.id AS a_id, a.value AS a_value
    FROM  [table1] as a
    UNION ALL
    SELECT b.id AS b_id, b.value AS b_value
    FROM  [table2] as b
) tmp
GROUP BY tmp.a_id, tmp.a_value
HAVING COUNT(*) = 1
ORDER BY tmp.a_id
```

I get result:

```
  a_id     a_value
    3        5
    8      6
```

I need to know which column is from which table, e.g.

```
  a_id     a_value         b_id    b_value
    3        5                8      6
```

Any help would be appreciated !

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

You could add a column for tbl.  Something like:

```
SELECT
m.id
,m.value
INTO #tmp
FROM
( 
SELECT a.id AS id, a.value AS value
FROM  [table1] as a
UNION ALL
SELECT b.id AS id, b.value AS value
FROM  [table2] as b
) m
GROUP BY
m.id
,m.value
HAVING COUNT(*) = 1

CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX ix_tmpidvalue ON #tmp
    (
    id ASC
    ,value ASC
    )

SELECT *
FROM
( 
SELECT a.id AS id, a.value AS value, 'a' tbl
FROM  [table1] as a
UNION ALL
SELECT b.id AS id, b.value AS value, 'b' tbl
FROM  [table2] as b
) tmp
WHERE EXISTS
    (
    SELECT 1
    FROM #tmp n
    WHERE tmp.id = n.id
        AND tmp.value = n.value
    )
ORDER BY tmp.id
```

Comment: Just realized your count would not work the way you want then.  But you could put this into a temp table for analysis on what your looking for then check the ids with a count(*) = 1.

Comment: I added the FROM into the first query.  In such a hurry to try and help I forgot that.

Answer (score 0):

What about:

```
SELECT *
FROM ( 
    SELECT a.id, a.value, 'Table1' AS TableName
    FROM  [table1] as a
  UNION ALL
    SELECT b.id, b.value, 'Table2' AS TableName
    FROM  [table2] as b
) tmp
GROUP BY tmp.id, tmp.value, tmp.TableName
HAVING COUNT(*) = 1
ORDER BY tmp.id
```

Comment: i got SQL error, tmp only have a_id not id. Thanks ! Also, "TableName" is also sued as a new column so that the same rows added with the new column become NOT same !

Comment: I don't understand your comment. Why are you using a temp table? If you have additional requirements, please include them in your question. We can't provide a full answer unless you provide the full questiuon.

Comment: The "TableName" became a new column in table1 and table2 so that no rows are same even though they are if no the new column. thanks!